# How to solve a inequality with fractions and roots in denominator and numerator

Tags: inequality, fractions, radicals

The inequality is like that:
$$
    \sqrt{\frac{3x+1}{2}}>1
$$
I have no idea how should i begin with it.

Comment: Start by squaring the whole thing?

Comment: a condition must be given, from which you have to find this, so check it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The value $\sqrt a$ is greater than $1$ iff $a>1$.

Answer (score -2):

Square both sides since 1 is positive; then cross multiply; then solve. The question will then become like this: $3x - 3 > 0$.

Now, equate $3(x-1)=0$ giving $x=1$.

Next, consider the real number line as follows:

```
-           +      ( always take + from right and then - if power is odd;
```

---------1---------     otherwise the sign remains the same)

And since it gives us that $3x-3>0$, it follows that $x > 0$; Hence, we will take the positive value. And so, the answer $x$ belongs to $(1, \infty).$

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Please use punctuation and explain your thoughts more clearly.